# How to disable muting of line-in?

Tags: sound, alsa, mute

How can I disable muting of line-in in Sound Settings? Line-in input mutes every time I restore my alsamixer settings with

```
/usr/sbin/alsactl -f my_asound.state restore
```

Option "auto-mute" is disabled in my alsamixer settings.
Can I unmute this input programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It was necessary to unmute line-in, then run `alsactl store`, and then `restore` option of `alsactl` can be used.